# How to set an env variable conditionally in free marker template

Tags: linux, bash, templates, freemarker

I have a .ftl with some export statements and for a particular variable, I would like to do a conditional check if it exists and set. I followed the syntax mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122878) and my script looks like below

```
export my_app_name=${app_setttings.name}
export my_app_env=${my_app_env:-root}        # this is bash syntax but clasing with ftl syntax
```

I am getting the following error

```
Encountered ":", but was expecting one of:
"."
".."
<DOT_DOT_LESS>
.
.
.
<TERMINATING_EXCLAIM>
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker already uses `${...}` in its default syntax, so even `${app_settings.name}` will be a problem, since FreeMarker will try to evaluate it. So you should configure FreeMarker to use square bracket *interpolation* syntax instead, which looks like `[=...]` instead of `${...}`. On the same time, usually you want to set the tag syntax to square brackets as well. See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html

I'm not sure how/where FreeMarker is configured in your case. In Java it's like `configuration.setInterpolationSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX)` and `configuration.setTagSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_TAG_SYNTAX)`, and in `.properties` file it's like `interpolation_syntax=square_bracket` and `tag_syntax=square_bracket`.